# Is it Reasonble to run SFC /scannow everynight on your computer?

Tags: windows-7, sfc

On my computer (Win7 64-bit prof) i run every night a backupscript with robocopy and at the end the sfc /scannow command. I started this 2 years ago on my old computer, usually it showed me no Tags with [SR] (SR stands for System repair). But on my new Laptop it always shows lots of [SR] which cause the script to stop (Since i search with findstring for SR and then let it stop if it finds anything).

But today i started thinking more genereally is it really smart to do that, or should you only run SFC if your PC has problems? Is SFC maybe doing more damage to a good system or should it be no problem at all. Does it make any differnce for that consideration wether i start SFC from a running windows, or is it less "harmfull" to do it from Sysmte Recovery Environment?

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Any regular file system maintenance (defrag, indexing, etc.) is done automatically.  It's not necessary to run SFC unless you're troubleshooting a problem.

Comment: "not necessary" is not the type of answer i'm looking for. Is it damaging "yes" or "no" (with some explanation) is more the type of answer. Doesn't someone know?

Comment: @user54512 Your question was actually, "Is it reasonable...", to which I answered "no".  But is it damaging?  Generally not, _however_ it could be if your system had another problem (e.g. hardware faults, viruses).

Comment: Hi Jason (or anybody else), just stopped by again. Why would it be potentially dangerous if my system had a hardware fault or virus? In case of a virus, corrupted files would be restored with the original files. In case of - e.g. an errenous harddisk would have corrupted some system files, the same would apply: the errenous files would be replaced by the original ones - perfect. One could argue now that the files in the store might be errenous too, but then a file that was corrupted in the first place would be replaced by a file which is corrupted too. So no loss in this case also..

Answer (score 0):

If you have traditional spinning platter disks then nightly sfc is OK (but I wouldn't do it because it is a waste of time). If you have an SSD then you could be wearing it out. SSDs have a limited number of writes. sfc on a healthy system shouldn't generate too many writes and modern SSDs can handle a lot of writes, but it's a small downside for no upside.

Comment: I don't run SFC on a regular basis anymore, it finds so many "failures" that when you google them it turns out that there is nothing wrong just SFC thinks there is something...